# How do I turn debugging in disassembly off permanently?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, disassembly

Whilst debugging a console app in c# and VS2008, disassembly window appears uninvited.

I am debugging my code line by line using F11.  I have break points set and it starts off well then after a call in a method to open database connection, the debugger opens disassembly window and stays there.  I have right-clicked on disassembly tab and selected hide but the window pops again as soon as I hit F11.

How do I turn debugging in disassembly off permanently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Debug->Options and Settings`, uncheck the box for `Enable address-level debugging` and that should do what you want.

[image]

You also may want to check `Enable Just My Code` if it is not checked.

Comment: Thank you.  This did the trick.  I am new at this so I appreciate you taking the time to show me how.

Comment: If I helped you out be sure to mark the answer as accepted so your question does not keep coming up on the front page for questions with no accepted answers.